# Programmatically reading Emails from Exchange Sever 2003

Tags: vb.net, exchange-server-2003

We receive vendor confirmation of file feeds that we send out.  Some of our vendors will only send the confirmation through email.  I am trying to find some sample VB code that I can use to try and use, that I can schedule to go out and query an inbox and see if there is an email from a certain account and I then return the message body.  A lot of the articles that I have found discuss using Web DAV, but I am unfamiliar with it as well as trying to query Exchange Server.  I have found documentation for the apis for the new versions of Exchange Server, but I am having a hard time finding it for Exchange 2003.

Comment: You can definitely query an Exchange server using Exchange-specific calls but I would highly recommend going a simpler route and just using POP or IMAP. You'll find lots of sample code out there and you don't have to worry too much about the "Exchange-ness".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What ultimately helped me answer my question was this book "CDO & MAPI Programming".  You can download the sample code from [Here](http://examples.oreilly.com/9781565926653/).  Chapters 6 and 7 from the book are were really helpful in figuring this out.

Comment: you have not yet answered your question

Comment: There is sample code at the link provided as well as if you obtain a copy of the chapters then you will see how to use CDO & MAPI to solve the this issue of reading emails, without using WEBDEV.  So yes, I did answer my question, and yes I did give an alternative to WEBDEV like the question was asking for.